# How to save the images of the unlogged users

Tags: php, cookies

What is the best way to save the user created images, the users may be logged or not.
If cookies are best. Is it possible to save the large images in cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stroing  large images in cookie, You can store your image url along wth domain path.